# Why would I create a Conda env without an interpreter?

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, development-environment

After some issues adding my Conda env to PyCharm (Pro) I realized that my Conda env did not include an interpreter. My env was created with

```bash
conda create --name <name>
```

In PyCharm, I need to add interpreter and Conda executable for existing environments. I understand by this that I should create my environment with

```bash
conda create --name <name> python
```

Then I wonder, **why would I create a Conda env without an interpreter if I cannot use it in my tool?** Just trying to figure out how I should work with Conda.

Answer (score 2):

### Conda is a generic package manager

While Conda is closely tied to Python (it itself is implemented in Python) the environments it creates are not Python-specific. I regularly create environments that do not include a Python interpreter. Some specific examples include R environments, C++ compilation environments, or bioinformatics tool-specific environments (e.g., samtools). I definitely would not want Conda to assume that every environment I create should include a Python interpreter.

### Configuring Conda to always include Python

If you know with certainty that you want Python in every environment you ever create, then you have the option of adding `python` to the `create_default_packages` configuration option (see [Documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#adding-default-packages-to-new-environments-automatically)).

```
conda config --add create_default_packages python
```